# Open a PyQt6 Window on Pynput GlobalHotKey Press results in Broken Window

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt6, pynput

For my application I want to have a main window that has a button and a shortcut handler that is able to catch Hotkeys even when the python app is not in focus. The easiest solution was to use a Pynput Global HotKey Listener.
The Code below brings this functionality but the window that is opened from the hotkey is broken.
It has no content, can't be moved, minimized or closed. It also sometimes crahses the application entirely.
The Window opened from the button on the other hand works perfectly fine even though both are calling the same method.

This doesn't make sense to me so all help is greatly appreciated.

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout
from pynput import keyboard

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Main Window")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 300, 200)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.button = QPushButton("Open Second Window")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.open_second_window)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)

        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.show()

    def open_second_window(self):
        self.second_window = SecondWindow()
        self.second_window.show()

class SecondWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Second Window")
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 300, 200)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.button = QPushButton("Close")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.close)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)

        self.setLayout(layout)

class HotKeyListener:
    def __init__(self):
        self.listener = keyboard.GlobalHotKeys({"<ctrl>+<alt>+i": self.open_second_window})
        self.listener.start()

    def open_second_window(self):
        second_window = SecondWindow()
        second_window.show()

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    hotkey_listener = HotKeyListener()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: UI elements are *not* thread safe, and shall never be accessed from external threads, which is exactly what pynput listeners are. The only safe and acceptable way to communicate between threads and UI is through signals and slots. I seem to remember an existing post on this specific matter, but I cannot find it right now, in the meantime, do some research on Qt multithreading and signal/slot communications.